# html background image not showing at all

Tags: html, css

I started a website from scratch so it is pretty empty so far. I started the first div, the css and then I hit a problem like I always do. The background image would not show up. I tried to change the directory to the same as the HTML (it is in /assets/img/ usually). I also put it into photoshop and exported it as a png incase that was the problem. When I use a background-color code it works but I can't get the image to work. Ill show code below:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/img/logo.png"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/logo.png"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style1.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1>content</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font: 1em/1.2 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
width: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
background-image: url('../assets/img/backdrop.png');
background-color: transparent;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
margin: 0 0 .5em;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 1.1;
}

h1 { font-size: 2.25em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.75em; }
h3 { font-size: 1.375em; }
h4 { font-size: 1.125em; }
h5 { font-size: 1em; }
h6 { font-size: .875em; }

#content {
max-width: 80em;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

.img-responsive { max-width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Is the link to your image correct?

Comment: If you check the developer tools in your browser, it will most likely give you an error. Most likely it will give a 404 error. To check your developer tools, press F12 on your keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an error in your img link change this :

```
background-image: url('../assets/img/backdrop.png');
```

to this :

```
background-image: url('../img/backdrop.png');
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you didn't need to put the assets there.

Comment: When you load your img, you are in /assets/css , so when you do ".." you are in assets folder, if you put assets again, it can't found folder.

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to

```
background-image: url('../img/backdrop.png');
```